# Telerik RadListView and drag&drop(for Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, telerik, windows-phone-8.1

I use Telerik for Windows Universal(Windows Phone 8.1).  I need drag&drop from RadListView to RadListView. I read official [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/windows-universal/controls/radlistview/features/listview-gestures), but I have not found the answer.There are about ItemDragStartingContext, DragAction, but there is no complete example drag&drop, only reorder example.  Is it possible? If yes - I need example drag&drop between RadListView.

Answer (score 0):

I received a answer on the official forums: RadListView is not supported drag&drop, only reorder. I use the standard ListView - it is work with drag&drop and reorder.